# Axios and fetch working on iOS but not working on Android

Tags: android, react-native, axios, fetch

I am trying to make a GET request from a server, I tried with fetch(), which perfectly works on iOS emulator, but it's not working on android (whether it's on an emulator or on a debug apk).

I tried several things from all over stackoverflow, none of them are working. Here is what I tried:

- http and https requests
- using axios (logging Network Error), fetch (Network request failed) or XMLHttpRequest
- adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to `AndroidManifest.xml`
- adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"` to `AndroidManifest.xml`

I don't know what to try next, neither how to debug to have a better understanding of what is happening.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: after you added the network and HTTP permission, did you save and rebuild the project?

Comment: When you say rebuild, is it about a very long react-bundle command and ./gradlew assembleDebug ? If yes, it's what I do each time I try a new debug apk on my android phone

Comment: In ios, it works that means your code is correct, it  is possibly  the permission problem

Comment: could you give what the error info is? one in android studio log, the other is your own network log info